# Find occurences of an element in a list of sublists

Tags: list, prolog

I'm working on a Prolog program that will generate a CYK parse table after being given a set of productions.  I am stuck on forming Row 1, which creates a cell (list) containing all of the non-terminals that a given terminal can be derived from.  Here's what I've got so far:

Here are the productions (upper-case = non-terminal, lower-case = terminal):

```
productions(book,[["S","AB"],["S","BB"],["A","CC"],
                  ["A","AB"],["A","a"],["B","BB"],
                  ["B","CA"],["B","b"],["C","BA"],
                  ["C","AA"],["C","b"]]).
```

and here is my current 'solution' (it's close but not correct):

```
form_row1_cell(StringElement,ProductionsList,Row1Cell) :- 
    form(StringElement,ProductionsList,Row1Cell).

form(_,[],[]).
form(A,[[X,Y]|T],[R|Rtail]) :- member(A,[X,Y]), !, R=X, form(A,T,Rtail).
form(A,[_|T],[_|Rtail]) :- form(A,T,Rtail).
```

and finally, here is the goal I am calling along with the output.  It returns a list that contains the correct elements (calling with "a" should give a list of just ["A"], "b" should give a list of ["B","C"]), but it's giving me a bunch of extra output as well.

```
?- productions(book,BookProds),form_row1_cell("a",BookProds,Cell).
BookProds = [["S", "AB"], ["S", "BB"], ["A", "CC"], ["A", "AB"], ["A", "a"], ["B", "BB"], ["B", "CA"], ["B"|...], [...|...]|...],
Cell = [_G2912, _G2915, _G2918, _G2921, "A", _G2933, _G2936, _G2939, _G2942|...].
```

So, you see that "A" is in the resulting list, which is correct, but I can't figure out why it's giving me all the extra stuff.  I assume that I am not performing the recursion correctly, I am still fairly new to Prolog.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: If `member(A, [X,Y])` fails, then `form(A, [_|T], [_|Rtail])` will put `_` (anonymous variable) at the head of your list. All of the `_Gxxxx` variables you see are every time that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the third definition of `form/3`: instead of this

```
form(A,[_|T],[_|Rtail]) :- form(A,T,Rtail).
```

you should write

```
form(A,[_|T],L):- form(A,T,L).
```

In this way you avoid to add undefined elements into the list.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you, my friend.  I knew I was close!  Cheers.